# Is it possible to wrap function such as Geolocation.watchPosition() in a Promise?

Tags: javascript, geolocation, async-await, ecmascript-2017

I wonder if it's possible to wrap `Geolocation.watchPosition()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/watchPosition in a Promise and use it with `async/await` idioms in a way it does it's work; constantly returns positions whenever a device's location changes and invokes succeeding functions.

```
// Example Class
class Geo {
  // Wrap in Promise
  getCurrentPosition(options) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(resolve, reject, options)
    })
  }

  // Wrap in Promise
  watchCurrentPosition(options) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(resolve, reject, options)
    })
  }

  // Works well.
  async currentPosition() {
    try {
      let position = await this.getCurrentPosition()
      // do something with position.     
    }
    catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  }

  // Any way...?
  async watchPosition() {
    try {
      let position = await this.watchCurrentPosition()
      // do something with position whenever location changes. 
      // Invoking recursively do the job but doesn't feel right.
      watchPosition()
    }
    catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Something like [this Observables proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-observable/blob/master/README.md)?

Comment: This *could* be done, but promises are ideal for things that need to happen once. A listener model -- such as an Observable -- would be much more obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not yet.

The pattern you're describing is an *Observable* - there isn't language support for it in Javascript, but it's coming.

In ES2015 we got generators: `function*` & `yield`, which allowed *Iterators* - pulling each `yield` with a `for`...`of` loop.

Generators also support push *Observers*, with `var valToGet = yield foo;` and `generator.next(valToPush);` syntax.

Generators are synchronous - they're just passing a single thread back and forth.

In ES2017 we got `async` & `await` - these use generators under the covers to convert each `await` in an `async function` into a `yield new Promise(...`. The `async function` becomes a *iterator* of *promises*.

Ideally we would be able to do something like this:

```
async watchPosition*() {
    try {
        while(this.enabled) {
            // Loop each time navigator.geolocation.watchPosition fires success
            const position = await this.watchCurrentPosition();

            // Pass back to the listener until generator.next
            const atDestination = yield position;
            if(atDestination)
                break; // We're here, stop watching
        }
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, `async function*` isn't supported yet - functions can be generators or `async`, but not both. There also isn't the nice `for`...`of` syntax like there is for iterators, just the clunky `generator.next(pushValue)`, so consuming this hypothetical method is a little ugly:

```
async listener() { 
    const generator = Geo.watchPosition();
    let item = await generator.next(false);
    while (!item.done) {
        // Update UI
        const atDestination = areWeThereYet(item.value);
        item = await generator.next(atDestination);
    }
}
```

So asynchronous iterators/observables are coming, but there's lots to sort out first.

In the mean time there are some exceptional libraries that support observer patterns and are available now, such as [RxJS](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS).